# How do I create access control

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, access-control

Hi I am new to oracle express application and I am having trouble trying to create access control for different levels of users. I am not the admin, I am just the developer and cannot create users. 
So far I have zero users. I want to create users. Not sure if it is possible. I don't  have the function available.

The image below shows an error. Don't know how to solve this. I am assuming it is not possible to create access control  if I don't have users. I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: If you're not the administrator, who is? Seems like you should be asking them to help?

Comment: The schema assigned to the workspace needs system privileges CREATE TABLE etc

Comment: My teacher is the admin. He is not letting is create users. Not sure why. I haven't gotten a response from him. So far I am hiding some of content from the developer (that's me). To show evidence of creating this access control. Who can view it and who can't. But like I said since I can't create. I can only hide it from myself. That doesn't sound right, but It is my only option. If there is another pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

This won't help you right now, and I know you're not in control of this, but you should encourage your teacher or administrators to update the version of Oracle APEX which is being used.

The version you're using (APEX 5.0) implemented access control by creating a table in your database schema.  In newer versions of APEX, local access control is embedded as part of the framework itself.

Your instructions may be using a specific curriculum associated with this version of APEX, and it would be time-consuming to update.  But please do let them know for future classes that Oracle does provide a completely free curriculum, with a permissive use license.

[Here](https://apex.oracle.com/en/learn/education/) is more information about the curriculum, and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/announcing-the-availability-of-oracle-apex-191-free-curriculum-v2) was the blog announcement.